# How to set up Glassfish for production?

Tags: java, glassfish

This is probably a newbie question, but I can't find good answers using Google. So, here I am.

I have developed a for-internal-use webapp that runs on Glassfish. I have used `http://localhost:8080/webapp-name` during development. Now I need to deploy the app to a server. Suppose the server has an ip address 192.168.5.18. My goal is to make the app available via something like `http://192.168.5.18:9090/webapp-name`. So, how can I achieve that? Is Glassfish itself alone enough? Do I need to install extra modules, such as `mod-jk`, on that server?

BTW, the webapp is developed under Glassfish 4.

**Edit**

In an effort to make my question more specific, I'd like to add some details.

Suppose I have installed Glassfish on a server of IP address 192.168.5.18, and have created a domain `domain1` with port `9090`. So, after I successfully run this command `asadmin start-domain domain1`, and have my app deployed via `asadmin deploy webapp-name.war`, will the app will be available via `http://192.168.5.18:9090/webapp-name`?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, you can achieve that with plain Glassfish. As for mod_jk, that's an Apache httpd module, I hope you know the difference between Apache and Glassfish. You might want to continue googling until you have a clearer picture, but for here the question is too broad.

Comment: .@Kayaman Can you tell me how I can make the question more specific? BTW, I do understand the difference between Glassfish and Apache HTTP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No extras are nedded, just some glassfish configuration, if glassfish domain was created with default values you should acces to the admin console with http://your.ip:4848, then go to configuration, server-config, network-listeners and edit the port (default is 8080).
Also you can create a new domain with asadmin tool, something like

```
    dir/whereglassfish/glassfish/bin/asadmin create-domain domainName -instanceport 9090
```

**Edited**
Yes, it will behave exactly like you say, but if you have acces to the admin console (the one in the 4848 port b default), you could easily upload your war from the browser, select the path root of the application (by default the war name, or just "/" to make your app the main app, accessible directly from `http://yourip:9090`), and other options like precompile the jsp's and validate the beans, etc..

Comment: .@rekiem87 I have updated my question. Can you confirm that once the domain is created appropriately, the ip of the server can be used in place of `localhost`? Thank you very much.